# Rails Search Query for LIKE - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

There are few posts like this question floating around but none solves my issue. Most tutorials today seem to use the old way (Rails < 3). I'm on Rails 4.

**In my root, I have:**

```
<%= form_tag search_supports_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**In the controller:**

```
  #search_supports#index
  if params[:search]
    @supports = Support.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
  else
    @supports = Support.find(:all)
  end
```

For testing, if I have, in controller, `@supports = Support.all`, I'd get back all supports in views using `@supports.each` block.

The exact error I'm getting is:

```
Couldn't find all Supports with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["name LIKE ?", "%[:search]%"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

Is there a Rails 4 of doing this search? If yes, may I have a link with your answer to read up on? **PS: I'm still learning Rails.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks suspiciously like Rails 2 code.

```
Support.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
```

In Rails 4 syntax it should look like:

```
Support.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

I'd recommend the Rails guide for further reading on the [ActiveRecord Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: I knew my code looks ancient lol. That worked! Thanks! I have to wait 6mins before accepting this answer ;)